# Xquery get the children nodes by passing parent value at run time

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I need to pass a value at run time get all the childen elements.

For example this is my XML:

```
<person>
   <details1>
      <name>jack</name>
      <age>26</age>
   </details1>
   <details2>
      <name>john</name>
      <age>48</age>
   </details2>
</person>
```

And my query:

```
let $y as xs:string := "details1"
let $x := fn:doc(cts:uri-match('*person.xml'))
return $x/$y
```

So here I am expecting the result as

```
<details1>
<name>jack</name>
<age>26</age>
</details1>
```

but it returns the same name as that of $y i.e. "details1"

or if I query this way

```
let $y as xs:string := "details1"
let $x := fn:doc(cts:uri-match('*person.xml'))
return $x//$y
```

the result would be "details1" for 12 times

I am new to XQuery please help me in solving the issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you attempt to use a string `$y` as a node step. However, in XPath/XQuery a path step is different from a string, so you can't simple add a string as path step. Instead, you could look for all descendent elements with the requirement that they do have the same name, i.e.:

```
let $y as xs:string := "details1"
let $x := fn:doc(cts:uri-match('*person.xml'))
return $x/*[name(.) = $y]
```

Comment: Using `name()` is almost always a bad idea.  Everytime you use it, you should consider whether `node-name()`, or sometimes even `local-name()`, is not better instead).

Answer (score 1):

As drkk said, you have to look at the name of the element.  But using `name()` is dangerous.  It returns the lexical name of the element, which might be `ns:elem` if the element has a prefix.  And the prefix can be different in every document, even for the same namespace.  So either you match only by local name:

```
let $y as xs:string := 'details1'
let $x := fn:doc(cts:uri-match('*person.xml'))
return
   $x/*[local-name(.) eq $y]
```

Or better, match a QName (note the `node-name()` usage):

```
let $y as xs:string := xs:QName('details1')
let $x := fn:doc(cts:uri-match('*person.xml'))
return
   $x/*[node-name(.) eq $y]
```

and if the element name is within a namespace (note the difference between `xs:QName()` and `fn:QName()`):

```
let $y as xs:string := fn:QName('namespace-uri', 'details1')
let $x := fn:doc(cts:uri-match('*person.xml'))
return
   $x/*[node-name(.) eq $y]
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use xdmp:value() to evaluate the XPath dynamically:

```
let $y as xs:string := "details1"
let $x := fn:doc(cts:uri-match('*person.xml'))
return xdmp:value("$x/" || $y)
```

If $x is a large data set, that approach can have performance benefits by removing the need to get the element name for every document in the set.

For more detail, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value?q=xdmp:value&v=8.0&api=true

Hoping that helps,

Comment: With all the usual warnings about dynamic evaluation, input sanitization, error detection, etc.

Comment: Agreed, Florent, those are important concerns when the name string is coming from an unknown external source.  cts:valid-index-path() offers one way to validate paths though it is perhaps more strict than needed for some cases.